# Criar procedure no mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou tentando criar a segunda precedure no mysql, mas quando dou o enter na primeira linha do declare da o seguinte erro:

ERROR 1064 (42000)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE finaliza_expedicao (IN expedicao_id INT)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE id_prod INT;
    DECLARE id_conf INT;
    DECLARE id_int INT;

        SELECT id INTO id_prod FROM expedicao WHERE codigo = expedicao_id;
    SELECT conferencia_id INTO id_conf FROM separacao WHERE expedicao_id = id_prod;
        SELECT interno_id INTO id_int WHERE conferencia_id = id_conf
    UPDATE volume SET contido_em_id = NULL, area_id = NULL, expedicao_id = id_prod 

WHERE id = id_int;
    UPDATE expedicao SET data_fim = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d H:i:s') WHERE id = 

id_prod;
    END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Falta o from table em uma das suas atribuições de variável, procure sempre Indentar melhor o código para melhor legibilidade e até mesmo achar os erros, segue o código, só alterar a tag `[sua_tabela]` pela tabela a qual pertence a query.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS finaliza_expedicao;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE finaliza_expedicao (IN expedicao_id INT)
BEGIN

    DECLARE id_prod INT;
    DECLARE id_conf INT;
    DECLARE id_int INT;

    SELECT 
                id 
        INTO id_prod 
        FROM expedicao 
        WHERE codigo = expedicao_id;

    SELECT 
                conferencia_id 
        INTO id_conf 
        FROM separacao 
        WHERE expedicao_id = id_prod;

        SELECT 
                    interno_id  
        INTO id_int 
        FROM [sua_tabela]
        WHERE conferencia_id = id_conf;

    UPDATE volume 
                SET contido_em_id = NULL, 
                        area_id = NULL, 
                        expedicao_id = id_prod 
        WHERE id = id_int;

        UPDATE expedicao 
                SET data_fim = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d H:i:s') 
        WHERE id = id_prod;
END
|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte erro quando fui testar ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';

Comment: Você substituiu a tag `[sua_tabela]`?
Pq na pergunta você não colocou ai não sabia o nome

Comment: Tinha um ; a mais.